# mod_rewrite: Convert 'Folders' in URL Into Query Parameters

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to take a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/valOne/valTwo/valThree/valFour/valFive
```

and convert it to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?one=valOne&two=valTwo&three=valThree&four=valFour&five=valFive
```

I really only need a few query parameters for my application so the Regular Expression could have these five hard coded, but it would be nice if it could dynamically create new query parameters as additional 'folders' are added to the URL. Additionally, not all five folders or QPs will always be present, so it must be able handle that appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here’s a mod_rewrite rule that meets your needs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4&five=$5
```

But it would be certainly easier if you parse the requested URI path with PHP instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
var_dump($segments);
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! One question what does this do:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

??

Comment: It checks if the requested URI can be mapped onto an existing file (`-f`). If so, the rule is not applied. Otherwise every URI would be redirected to `index.php` (even `index.php` itself as it also would be matched by `[^/]*`). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Where would I put that PHP script?
It seems like if I put it in site.com/Dir1/default.php and the url were site.com/Dir1/Dir2/default.php that  Dir1/ would never execute (did that with a quick test).

Comment: The first two lines would go in your Apache config, or an .htaccess file, not a PHP script.