# mod_rewrite how to: convert folders in url to get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to basically do the same thing as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658978/mod-rewrite-convert-folders-in-url-into-query-parameters) ie to convert folders in url into query-parameters, and I like the rewrite rules given there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) (myserver) [NC]  #my addition for my sandbox
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4&five=$5
```

but will that work in the .htaccess file or does it need to go in the http.conf file?

I am testing this out on my sandbox machine which uses http://172.xx.xx.xx/myserver/
for this web apps url.  On the actual server of course there is no /myserver/ folder needed.
So on the actual server I could maybe get away with putting  a .htaccess file in the root or maybe the mod directive in the http.conf (or can't I?) but on my sandbox what can I do to get this working?

To reiterate: if I use this url: http://my.ip.add.res/myserver/aaa/bbb/ccc
I want it rewritten to: /myserver/index.php?one=aaa&two=bbb&three=ccc  etc
Should I put the command in the .htaccess in the myserver folder or elsewhere?

PS I am using apache 2.2.3 on CentOS.

Comment: I should mention that I put those rules in the myserver folder's htaccess file it it doesn't work, i get a 404 error.  I also tried putting it in the root's .htaccess file but same result.

Comment: If you are using mod_rewrite via .htaccess on a site whose URL directories do not match the physical directories, you need a RewriteBase directive.  Do you have one?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just putting it in the .htaccess file for now, seems to work as desired and I suspect it'll be good on the production site too.

PS: I have no RewriteBase defined.